# Looking for songs with tension-building guitar hammer-ons

Tags: genre, style, technique

I recently first listened to '[Can't Stop' by the Red Hot Chili Peppers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfOdWSiyWoc). I really like how this song builds up tension in the beginning using a (I think) guitar hammer-ons technique.
I could swear I heard other songs beginning like this or at least similarly.
Therefor I was hoping this community could help me identify these songs.

I play competition [freestyle dogfrisbee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_dog#Freestyle), and it's always a challenge to find good songs to match the choreographed routine I do with my dogs, I'm hoping to find some nice candidates in your answers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Thunderstruck has some good hammer on and pull offs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5iTQf5PDyY

Answer (score 1):

[The Handler - Muse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BF1DQr5dKW8) has a huge bridge that Matt plays SOLELY with hammer-ons and pull-offs after the second chorus at 2:19.